Is it possible to change the host for a localhost server?
Lets say I want to have a friend run my project that runs web sockets and a few other local servers on my network so me and my other friends can test my project. If the friend who hosted the web sockets had to leave, he would have to close the web sockets, and that would throw things off.
I have a few other servers running that each client is hosting separately (Vite and Express, but they don't have any part in this), and the web pages in each server are connecting to the web sockets from that one host. So as you can see, the host disconnecting is an issue. My other servers run off of those web sockets.
Am I able to have multiple hosts (where the next host takes care of all the requests and socket messages if the current host is gone), or have something transfer the hosting to the next person (The person who connected after the host before disconnection)?

Sounds like you need load balancer, something like this

Yeah, a load balancer, or (I literally just of this) something that will keep the servers running till all clients are gone for a certain amount of time.
I'll look into this. I have heard of Socket IO before. :)

you can achieve this even if you aren't using socketIo for websockets. The actual load-balancing is done by servers like Nginx but load-balancing websocket servers is bit complicated compared to http servers.

I rise to every challenge, I'll just need help with some of them.
I'll definitely look into this some more.

For testing you can just run the websocket server on your own machine, but listening to an address on network instead on one involving localhost.  I've done this under windows, but needed to change the firewall rules to allow my machine to serve requests received from the network.

"Leave" means, we had been working in one place, like a lab, and then he went home for dinner?

I am building a game library for my friends. So if they come over, we can play the games I made to see if the tests I made work. So not a lab necessarily, more like a studio or living room. But yeah, they would eventually have to leave for dinner. I just wanted to give only the important details in my question.

@benc I have been pondering this question for a while now. I'm using Express to start up my servers and web sockets. What if I made a script that imports (not requires) express and ws? That way if I need to access something on a server, and it was taken down, the script can start them up again. That should be okay, right?

@Alex - (I think understand what you are describing)... if you have a script that restarts everything so it is happy, that should work. Those kind of start/stop/reconnect scripts are often what keeps the world running. The best advice I can add is just layer in as much logging and error handling as you can, so when something weird happens, you don't "start from zero".

Logging is what I do best. Thanks for the advice.

In short, the answer is yes.
Properly provisioning a corner of the internet (your own DNS domain, paying for a hosting, etc.) is well covered by others. This answer is an alternative approach, which can be done, with some context and limitations.
For your scenario, there's probably a couple features that need to be implemented, like putting re-connection logic in the app. Basically if the server you connect to disappears, your app should be trying to find on the network again, and then return to normal behavior, rather than quitting on the first returned error.
Other problems might be better handled in the network configuration of the web-app and its dependencies.
This might be an extreme example solution, but some people have projects that are using a couple of randomly selected (but fixed IP) addresses in the 17.0.0.0 subnet, which is the Class A private network address space. The chances that a truly-randomly selected set of 4 address would collide in a class A subnet are pretty low. But don't get half-clever and think: nobody else would ever do this on the 17 network, so I'm going to use 17.0.0.1 and 17.0.0.2.
